# How to make responsive png sequence?

Tags: html, css

I am trying make responsive png sequences.

My tried code is here. What is wrong with code?
 1. if i removed background-size :100%; it shows image until and unless it is invisible.
2. It is not responsive. (if i comment background-size :100%)
CSS

```
 .eye {
      position: relative;
      width: 70%;
      margin: -10% auto 0 auto; /* positioning tweak */
    }
    .pngseq{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background:  url('http://arnoculus.com/img/eye-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0%;
      background-size: 100%;
      animation: play 3s steps(58) infinite;
    }
@-webkit-keyframes play {
    from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -30740px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -30740px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -30740px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -30740px; }
}

@keyframes play {
     from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -30740px; }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="eye">
      <div class="pngseq">
      </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/ncj4r9nz/)**

Comment: Could you be more specific on "code is not working" and what is expected? Thanks [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You have several mistakes...

Here is your code working

```css
.eye {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: -10% auto 0 auto; /* positioning tweak */
}
 
.pngseq{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:  url('http://arnoculus.com/img/eye-sprite.png') no-repeat 0 0%;
    background-size: 5800%;
    animation: play 3s steps(57) infinite; 
}

@keyframes play {
    from { background-position:    0px 0px; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="eye">
    
    <div class="pngseq">
        
    </div>
    
</div>
```

It is shaking a bit, maybe the original image isn't accurate, or maybe working with percentages at this sizes has some rounding error; I don't know for sure.

Comment: nice answer. Thanks for that. can u explain me in short. ` height: 800px;` i dont want fixed height.

Comment: Your original code had height 0px, and wasn't showing because of that. Just set the height that you like.

Comment: u didnt get my point. i just want responsive height. and i tried with 100%, auto etc but that not working

Comment: Yes, I get your point. I have made the *png sequence* responsive. Making your div also responsive is easy, just set it to whatever you want.